# handle exception in try catch block

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a switch case scenario where I know beforehand that there is a high level of opportunity that the user might not set the the rules with the right categories. it's totally ok for me as soon as i can pop up a dialog showing instructions what to do in order to run the program. However i am missing something and here is my question.

When i test a scenario as per above the cursor goes through the default case, and pops up the error. How can i make it goes into my catch block?

```
try  
{
    switch (userInput)
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            if (condition)
            {
               some code here
            }
            else
            {
                throw error();
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            postingType = smth;
            break;
        default:
            throw Global::error("here blows the error and does not move on to the catch");
    }
}
catch(exception::Error)
{
    info("test");
}
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Thank you in advance and have a nice evening.

H.

Comment: Not sure about axapta, but normal C# would be `throw new Exception("message");` and then `catch(Exception e)`.

Comment: The code is not C# and even in Managed C++ it will not compile. Provide a real working example.

Comment: Your `else` will never fire. Please provide a meaningful example. We can't guess at what your environment is--you have to tell us.

Comment: My question is more like - how to theoretically handle the default case (after case 4)? - My only concern is that it stops when hit the error, rather then move on to the catch block
 Everything above is ok.

Comment: Below example shows your code would have gone through catch statement inside default case. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa893385.aspx#Sample 2: error Method to Write Exception to Infolog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that exceptions generally aren't caught inside database transactions. I explained it with a little more details in [the thread about the same question in the Dynamics community forum](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/238663/), where it's been marked as the verified answer.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know axapta, but logically it looks like you can achieve this behaviour without throwing an error (which is probably a better idea, since this is really a validation error rather than an application error).

How about:

```
  switch (userInput)
  {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        if (condition)

        {
           some code here
        }
        else
        {
            throw error();
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        postingType = smth;
        break;
    default:
        info("test");
        //handle invalid user input here.
        break;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, there is userInput in the switch case, As mentioned the code goes into the default case and runs out. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that's what i will be using as workaround until i get to a better solution. Enjoy!

Comment: Sure, please mark as answer if that resolves your issue.